# Loading an image into a RecyclerView cell

Tags: kotlin, gson, moshi

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val itunesStoreItemTitle = itunes.results.get(position)
    val imageURL = itunesStoreItemTitle.artworkUrl100
    //val inputStream = URL(imageURL).openStream()
    //val posterImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
    holder?.view?.textView_iTunes_title?.text = itunesStoreItemTitle.collectionName
    //holder?.view?.imageView_itunes?.setImageBitmap(posterImage)
    holder?.view?.textView_iTunes_Description?.text = itunesStoreItemTitle.longDescription
}
```

from my MainActivity class

```
fun fetchJSON() {
    println("Attempting to fetch JSON")
    val url = URL(BASE_URL).addParameters(iTunesMap)

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response?.body?.string()

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val iTunesFeed = gson.fromJson(body, iTunesFeed::class.java)
            
            runOnUiThread {
                recyclerView_main.adapter = MoshiAdapter(iTunesFeed)
            }
            println(body)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failed to fetch data")
        }
    })
}
```

I am trying to load images into my RecyclerView cell but it crashes on the first commented line.

CRASH LOG

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.oneorangetree.itunessearch, PID: 17091
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1072)
        at com.oneorangetree.itunessearch.adapters.MoshiAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MoshiAdapter.kt:30)
        at com.oneorangetree.itunessearch.adapters.MoshiAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MoshiAdapter.kt:14)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1843)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: please show your LogCat

Comment: @GianhTran added crash log

Answer (score 0):

your issue is very clear, `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs when you try to access network on your main thread, please use Rx or AsyncTask to handle network request, refer [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)